# same index multiple times on ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I want to show 2 custom widgets and listview(api data). I can't use `column`.(Because I want to scroll one time)

**In here, missing 0 and 1 data coming from api**

```
  ListView.builder(
      itemCount: get.length,//3
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if(index == 0){
         return Text('Generate By Developer');
        }
        if(index == 1){
         return Text('Generate By Developer');
        }
        return Bubble(
            style: styleSomebody,
            child: Container(
              ...
            ));
      }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tweak the count and the index.

```
  ListView.builder(
      itemCount: get.length + 2, // add room for the two extra
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if(index == 0){
         return Text('Generate By Developer');
        }
        if(index == 1){
         return Text('Generate By Developer');
        }
        index -= 2; // decrement index so that it's now in the range [0..length]
        return Bubble(
            style: styleSomebody,
            child: Container(
              ... 
            ));
      }),
```